Can't create two sessions- one fails one works
I have a post request in Django views from which I am calling a Selenium WebDriver. I am running it on Linux.
I have set the DISPLAY in the OS environment.
Now when I call the request it does open the Selenium browser normally, but when the driver is still open and I call the request again the Selenium browser can't create the session.
DJANGO uses wsgi application.
Switching to asgi may not work.
I was expecting to have two drivers open but it fails on the second one. Threading is not an issue here

class Test(generics.CreateAPIView):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        searchDict = dict(request.data)
        profile = searchDict['profile']
        threading.Thread(target=self.runDriver, args = (profile,)).start()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    def runDriver(self, profile):
        br = Driver()
        useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/121.0.0.0'

        profile_name = profile
        username = 'samsan'
        password = '##1234sAMIUL.'
        br.createUCDriver(useragent, profile_name)
        dr = br.ucDriver
        dr.get('https://www.google.com/')

        time.sleep(10)
        dr.get(dr.current_url)

This is the Driver class:
class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = None
        self.ucDriver = None
        self.waitTime = 10
        # self.logger = Logger()
        # self.executable = input("Please enter chrome executable path: ")
        self.executable = "seleniumDriver/chromedriver-mac-arm64/chromedriver"
    def createUCDriver(self, user_agent=None, profile_name='Profile 2'):


        #     os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':10.0'
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        if user_agent:
            options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={user_agent}')

        print('sys', sys.platform)
        if sys.platform == 'darwin':
            options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/Users/yourusername/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome')
        elif sys.platform == 'linux' or sys.platform == 'linux2':
            # options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/home/samiul/.config/google-chrome')
            options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent / "application" / "local" / "nfs"}')
        elif sys.platform == 'win32' or sys.platform == 'win64':
            options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')

        options.add_argument(f'--profile-directory={profile_name}')
        options.add_argument('--hide-crash-restore-bubble')
        options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
        options.add_argument('--disable-features=InfiniteSessionRestore')
        options.add_argument('--disable-features=PrivacySandboxSettings4')
        if sys.platform == 'darwin':
            print('mac')
            driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, use_subprocess=True)
        elif sys.platform == 'linux' or sys.platform == 'linux2':
            service = Service(executable_path=str(Path(__file__).parent/ 'chromeDriver'/ 'chromedriver-linux64' / 'chromedriver'))
            print('linux')
            # driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, use_subprocess=True, driver_executable_path=Path(__file__).parent/ 'chromeDriver'/ 'chromedriver-linux64' / 'chromedriver')
            driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, use_subprocess=True, service = service)
        elif sys.platform == 'win32' or sys.platform == 'win64':
            print('windows')
            try:
                driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, use_subprocess=True, driver_executable_path=str(Path(__file__).parent/ 'chromeDriver'/ 'chromedriver-win32' / 'chromedriver.exe'))
            except Exception as e:
                print('Error in starting Chrome', e)
        self.ucDriver = driver
        self.ucDriver.set_page_load_timeout(1.5 * 60)


don't set the profile... (you can't use a single profile for multiple drivers, but selenium will, by default, create a new temporary profile for use)

The problem was the google chrome directory. You can only make one chrome session with that chrome directory. This should because of the file SingletonLock, this prevents me to create multiple session with the chrome directory.
So I did a work around before I use the chrome directory, I simply make a temporary copy. The copied folder should be in the same folder as the original one. Then I use the chrome directory to make chrome sessions. Once I am done. I simply replace the original chrome directory with copied one but keeping the same original name.
You need this:
subprocess.run(['rsync', '-aqz', '--ignore-times', '--exclude=Singleton*', source_dir, dest_dir], check=True)

This way I can make many sessions as needed. And the cookies are not lost
I have kept one profile for one directory.
